# Scene Kit vehicle wheels disconnected from chassis

Tags: ios, scenekit

I'm trying to get a simple vehicle demo to work. If I create the chassis and wheels initially floating above the floor, then the wheels immediately drop to the floor but the chassis just floats above them.

If I build the scene so that the wheels start out resting on the floor, then they stay there, but the chassis floats UP (!) until it hovers in the air above the wheels. It floats up slowly, nice smooth animation.

How would you suggest I troubleshoot this?

```
//
//  Experiment1.swift
//  SKTrailerTow
//
//  Created by Philip Delaquess on 11/3/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 Philip Delaquess. All rights reserved.
//

import SceneKit

class Experiment1 : SCNScene {

    var chasis : SCNNode!

    override init () {
        super.init()

        addLights()
        addCamera()
        addFloor()
        addTractor()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func addLights () {
        let omni = SCNNode()
        omni.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 5, 0)
        omni.light = SCNLight()
        omni.light!.type = .omni
        self.rootNode.addChildNode(omni)
    }

    private func addCamera () {
        let camera = SCNNode()
        camera.position = SCNVector3Make(2.3, 1.4, 2.4)
        camera.camera = SCNCamera()
        self.rootNode.addChildNode(camera)

        let origin = SCNNode()
        self.rootNode.addChildNode(origin)
        let lookAt = SCNLookAtConstraint(target: origin)
        camera.constraints = [lookAt]
    }

    private func addFloor () {
        let floor = SCNNode()
        floor.position = SCNVector3Make(0, -0.1, 0)
        floor.geometry = SCNFloor()

        let body = SCNPhysicsBody.static()
        floor.physicsBody = body

        self.rootNode.addChildNode(floor)
    }

    private func addTractor () {
        chasis = SCNNode()
        chasis.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 0)
        chasis.geometry = SCNBox(width: 0.5, height: 0.1, length: 1.0, chamferRadius: 0.0)
        chasis.geometry!.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents = UIColor.yellow
        chasis.geometry!.firstMaterial!.specular.contents = UIColor.white

        let body = SCNPhysicsBody.dynamic()

        body.allowsResting = false
        body.mass = 80
        body.restitution = 0.1
        body.friction = 0.5
        body.rollingFriction = 0
        chasis.physicsBody = body
        self.rootNode.addChildNode(chasis)

        let flWheel = addWheel(toNode: chasis, atPosition: SCNVector3Make(0.25, 0, 0.5))
        let frWheel = addWheel(toNode: chasis, atPosition: SCNVector3Make(-0.25, 0, 0.5))
        let blWheel = addWheel(toNode: chasis, atPosition: SCNVector3Make(0.25, 0, -0.5))
        let brWheel = addWheel(toNode: chasis, atPosition: SCNVector3Make(-0.25, 0, -0.5))

        let vehicle = SCNPhysicsVehicle(chassisBody: body, wheels: [flWheel, frWheel, blWheel, brWheel])
        self.physicsWorld.addBehavior(vehicle)

    }

    private func addWheel (toNode node: SCNNode, atPosition pos: SCNVector3) -> SCNPhysicsVehicleWheel {
        let wheelNode = SCNNode()
        node.addChildNode(wheelNode)
        wheelNode.position = pos
        wheelNode.geometry = SCNSphere(radius: 0.1)
        wheelNode.geometry!.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red

        let wheel = SCNPhysicsVehicleWheel(node: wheelNode)
        let connPos = SCNVector3Make(pos.x * 1.5, pos.y, pos.z)
        wheel.connectionPosition = connPos

        return wheel
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out for myself. Apparently my wheels were too small. The radius of 0.1 didn't work. When I multiply all of the numeric literals by 10, it seems to work just fine!